# How can I get value from textarea, checkbox and radio button for sum?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to get result from all form field. When I change the value and also change the checkbox, answer of sum should be change
How can I get value from textarea, checkbox and radio button for sum?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
  $("#orderbutton").on("click", function () {
    var weight = parseFloat($("#weight").val());
    var destination = $("#destination").val();
    var insurance = $("#chkbox1").val();

    //construct output
    var msg = "<div> Result Of your order: </div>";
    msg += "<div> Package weight: " + weight + " pounds </div>";
    if (weight <= 25) {
      msg += "<div> Base cost based on your weight: $15.00  <div>";
    } else if (weight <= 50) {
      msg += "<div> Base cost based on your weight: $25.00 <div>";
    } else {
      msg += "<div> Base cost based on your weight: $40.00 </div>";
    }
    if (destination == "ny") {
      msg += "<div> Destination Selected: New York State( No extra cost)</div>";
    } else {
      msg += "<div> Destination Selected: Out Of State ($15.00 Extra)</div>";
    }
    if ($("#chkbox1").is(":checked")) {
      msg += "<div>Insurance option: Insurance Choosen($10.00 Added)<div>";
    } else {
      msg += "<div> Insurance option: Insurance Not Choosen($0.00 Added)</div>";
    }
    msg += "<div> Total price of order: </div>";

    $("#output").html(msg);
  }); // end event handler
}); // end document.ready
```

[sample result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfOjR.png)

Comment: Okay. So what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: you're not showing your relevant code, however, you can't sum 25 + "ny" + true. You can use data tags on those fields, so you can add them airthmetically. Something like `data-cost` so you can later get or set: $("#destination").data('cost') , $("#weight").data('cost') etc.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are calculating everything only on `click` of the order button. In order to have the sum recalculated on the change of textarea, checkbox and radio button, you can attach `.change()` event to your form elements.

For more details on `.change()` refer https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

For getting the textarea value

```
var textareaValue = $("#myTextarea").val();
```

for getting the checkbox value

```
var checkboxValue = $("#myCheckbox").is(":checked");
```

for getting the radio value

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='myRadios']:checked").val();
```

for calculating the sum

```
var sum = weight + (destination == "ny" ? 0 : 15) + (insurance ? 10 : 0);
msg += "<div> Total price of order: $" + sum.toFixed(2) + "</div>";
```

Comment: _"for getting the checkbox value"_ - this is not getting the value, but the `checked` state. Different things. Same for the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for getting the values for textarea, checkbox and radio button.

```
const textareaValue = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
const myCheckboxValue = document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked? 
Number(document.getElementById("myCheckbox").value) : 0;
let myRadioValue = 0;
const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("myRadioGroup");
for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
  if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
    myRadioValue = Number(radioButtons[i].value);
    break;
  }
}
const sum = textareaValue + myCheckboxValue + myRadioValue;
```